# How to prove Cantor's theorem by assuming an injection $g ∶ P(A) \to A$ and then arguing to a contradiction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Considering the set, $D = \{x ; (\forall\ x\in A)(\exists\ Y\in P(A))(g(Y)=x, x\notin Y)\}$. We then assume $g$ is an injection, how does one argue to a contradiction?

Comment: I want to prove it in this particular way, yes there are easier ways to prove Cantor's theorem, but in the problem I am struggling with there is a way to prove it as stated.

Comment: Try to check whether $g(D) \in D$ or $g(D) \not\in D$. Bot possibilities lead to a contradiction, and then you are done.

Answer (score 2):

If $g(D) \in D$ then by the definition of $D$ there exists $Y \in P(A)$ such that $g(Y) = g(D)$ and $g(D) \not \in Y$. But $g$ is injective hence $Y = D$, so $g(D) \not \in D$ and we have a contradiction.

On the other hand if $ g(D) \not\in D$ then in particular there exists $Y \in P(A)$ such that $g(Y) = g(D)$ and  $ g(D) \not\in Y$  (namely $Y = D$). This means that $g(D) \in D$ by the definition of $D$, which is again a contradiction.

We must have one of these two possibilities, so $g$ cannot exist.